# Finding constants $s$ and $t$ so that $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

How can I find $t$ and $s$ so that this matrix is diagonalizable?

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & t & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & s \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
               \end{pmatrix} $$

I started calculating the eigenvalues, and found $\lambda = 2$ and $\lambda=1$ (the last one with multiplicity of 2). I made a system and found also that $t$ must be zero and one eigenvector for $\lambda=1$ is $v = (1,1,0)^T$. For the other eigenvalue, I found $y=s$, so that $v=(2,1,1)^T$ if I choose $s=1$, for example. But what about the third vector? How can I found it so that $A$ can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
               \end{pmatrix} ?$$

Thank you very much! I am a very very beginner in linear algebra.

Comment: Try to solve $(A-1)(A-2) = 0$

Comment: The eigenvalues are the diagonal entries for triangular matrices, they don't need to be *calculated* (just saying in case you actually performed calculations for nothing)

Comment: Alternatively you can try to compute the dimension of the kernel of $A-Id$, which is very easy to do. Clearly $A-Id$ has rank $\leq 2$, and $A$ is diagonalizable iff $A-Id$ has rank $1$, so that there are two eigenvectors associated to $1$. This happens if $t=0$. If $t \neq 0$, it has rank $2$ so $t=0$ necessarily, and then $s$ can be anything. So $A$ is diagonalizable iff $t=0$.